# Select query to retrieve single row multi valued based on column value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Let's take two tables

table1 - node

```
node id | node_name | name_type
```

table2 - device

```
device_id | node_id | device_name
```

each node_id will have many combination of node_name and name_type

based on the name_type I should have select statement with single row placing those values in different columns

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help. Also, what have you tried? And, is `name_type` the same as `node_type`?

Comment: Is the second table (table2 - device) used at all?  Appears from what you've provided so far that only the first table (table1 - node) is needed.

Comment: Sample DATA
NODE_NAME  Node_NAMe   Device_name
RCRDCAJZ  XO                  SEHAQKTCD31
HOJ                  MECCA           SEHLNZ0RAMI
HSTN.POP  F_E           SEHLNZ0RAMI
HOJTTX          SCISS           SEHLNZ0RAMI
SCTNPASC CLLI           SEHWAUDIGO13
MRTWNJGA XO                   SEHWFMKVW64
If you see the above data SEHLNZ0RAMI this device name as three mapping all am looking for is select statement to display three rows in single rows
for example like below
col 1      col2                   col3             devicename
HOJ       HSTN.POP       HOJTTX      SEHLNZ0RAMI

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to include the sample data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). Do not put that in comments